# Get list of Artists from Album by using streams in JSP?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, java-stream

I have a list of Albums that have a list of Tracks that have a list of Artists. I want to get all artists involved in making tracks for each Album.

If I have one Album, I can pass that Album to a method Controller, get the list of Artists with Java streams and pass it to EL in .jsp file.

But I have a list of Albums that I iterate through in c:forEach and I want to do get list of Artists in each iteration. I tried to do it with EL, but Java 8 Streams are not supported in EL. Is there another way to do this?

Excerpt from Album.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="album")
@NamedQuery(name="Album.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Album a")
public class Album implements Serializable {

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Track
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="album")
    private List<Track> tracks;

    public List<Track> getTracks() {
        return this.tracks;
    }

}
```

Except from Track.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="track")
@NamedQuery(name="Track.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Track t")
public class Track implements Serializable {

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Album
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="albumid")
    private Album album;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Artist
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="producestracks"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="trackid")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="artistid")
            }
        )
    private List<Artist> artists;

    public Album getAlbum() {
        return this.album;
    }

    public List<Artist> getArtists() {
        return this.artists;
    }

}
```

Excerpt from jsp file.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Artists</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${allalbums }" var="a">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- THIS DOES NOT WORK HERE!!! -->
                <c:set var="ars" value="${a.tracks.stream()
                    .flatMap(t -> t.getArtists().stream())
                    .distinct()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()) }"/>
                <c:forEach items="${ars }" var="ar" varStatus="loop">
                    ${ar.name}
                    <c:if test="${!loop.last}">, </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Excerpt from AlbumController.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTracks", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getTracks(HttpServletRequest request) {
    List<Track> ts = tr.findAll();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("alltracks", ts);
    return "view/viewtracks";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use streams in jsp. You have two options here:

1. Do the loop in a traditional way in jsp. The same way you would have done it prior to java 8 streams. Even this is difficult due to the nature of the loop you need, that implies data manipulation. JSP is a presentation techonology, very read-only focused (except for simple variable assignment). You could create a `Set` with `<jsp:useBean>` but you would'n have a clean way to add elements to it.
2. Create a method that returns this for you and call it from jsp:

```java
return a.tracks.stream()
    .flatMap(t -> t.getArtists().stream())
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You may have the temptation to create this method directly in the entity class, but I would advice against this. Keep the entity for the entity purpose, and use a Helper class to provide supporting functions to use in jsp.

Comment: But I need to access that item form list to do this. How do I pass it from c:forEach to Controller?

Comment: To call functions from jsp to java you have to create a taglib in which reference static methods. I will update the answer with an example as soon as a have access to my computer :) Meanwhile here is a good and short tutorial https://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/2011/03/17/how-to-create-a-custom-taglib-containing-an-el-function-for-jsp/